# Subir archivo a google drive con Jython

Tags: python, google-drive, jython

poseo este código:

```
import json
import net
import system
import os
import system.net as net

token_acceso = event.source.parent.getComponent('txt_token').text
carpeta = event.source.parent.getComponent('txt_carpeta').text
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media"


headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+token_acceso}

selected_file = system.file.openFile("pdf")
#selected_file = system.file.openFile("")
if selected_file != None:
    # Obtenemos el nombre del archivo seleccionado
    file_name = os.path.basename(selected_file)
    
    print "nombre archivo: "+file_name
    #print "extension" + file_extension
    #print "file_name_with_extension" + file_name_with_extension
    
    # Leemos el contenido del archivo seleccionado
    file_content = system.file.readFileAsBytes(selected_file)

    params = {"name": file_name, "parents": [carpeta]}
    metadata = json.dumps(params)

    files = {
    "data": ("metadata", metadata, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"),
     #   "file": (file_name, file_content, "application/pdf"),
    "file": (file_name, file_content, "application/pdf")
    }

    client = net.httpClient()
    response = client.post(url, headers=headers, data=files)

    if response.good:
        print(response.json)
    else:
      #  print("Error: " + response.json)
      print ("error: " + response)
```

Y la consola me da esto:

```
nombre archivo: zzzzz.pdf
{'kind': u'drive#file', 'mimeType': u'application/json', 'name': u'Untitled', 'id': u'1ErwRgnOxuGe7SxYbnmVPjmIF8e2jvZSh'}
```

busco subir archivos a una carpeta especifica en mi drive. Lamentablemente me sube a la raíz del drive y un documento sin nombre con esto :

[image: archivo no subido satisfactoriamente]

Honestamente no sé qué más puedo hacer, llevo rato buscando :(

Busco subir archivo en una carpeta específica de mi drive, y el código que otorgo selecciono el archivo en este caso pdf e intento subirlo, sin conseguirlo satisfactoriamente.

Qué podría hacer para llevar a cabo mi requerimiento?

GRACIAS